# How to fix access to the requested resource which has been denied for Tomcat webapp?

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code-403

I have installed Tomcat in my machine and it is running fine. I am able to login to the administration manager. I have deployed a `.war` file which can be viewed on the Tomcat manager. The name of the file is `shim` (actually I am installing `freeshim`).

When I try to access shim on the browser using `192.168.1.65:8080/shim` I get a web administration interface of the `shim`. This is the message I get:

> This is the web administration interface for FreeSHIM. Web services are located "here".

When I click "here" in order for me to configure the Freeshim I get an error:

> HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied.

Where am I going wrong? How can I change this permission?

Comment: Kindly let me know why I have downvote

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is probably because your question is (1) Off-topic for SO as it is not about programming and likely belongs on [sf], and (2) hard to read; you should use standard punctuation and paragraphs, and (3) You haven't shown any effort to solve the problem yourself.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for details.

Answer (score 4):

HTTP Status 403 (Access to the requested resource has been denied) can indicate that either you typed 3+ incorrect credentials (try another web-browser) or you've some problem with configuration.

If you have not changed any configuration files, please examine the file `conf/tomcat-users.xml` in your installation (`locate tomcat-users.xml`). That file must contain the credentials to let you use Tomcat webapp.

For example, to add the manager-gui role to a user named `tomcat` with a password of `s3cret`, add the following to the config file listed above:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

Then you can access your webapps manager from `/manager/html` (e.g. reloading after config changes).

Read more: [Manager App HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html)

If you're trying to implement your own security constraint (in `web.xml`), try the following example (before `</web-app>` ending):

```
<!-- This security constraint protects your webapp interface. -->
<login-config>
  <!-- Define the Login Configuration -->
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Webapp</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <!-- Specifying a Secure Connection -->
  <user-data-constraint>
    <!-- transport-guarantee can be CONFIDENTIAL (forced SSL), INTEGRAL, or NONE -->
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<!-- Authorization, see: tomcat-users.xml --> 
<security-role>
  <role-name>*</role-name>
</security-role>
```

If you still having the problem, try:

- check if you're editing the right XML file,
- validate your XML files, e.g. `catalina.sh configtest` or `xmlstarlet val /etc/tomcat?/*.xml /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/*/WEB-INF/*.xml`,
- your `<url-pattern>` matches in your `<security-constraint>` or set to `/*`,
- check your Tomcat logs (e.g. `/var/log/tomcat7`),
- [increase logging level](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4119213/55075) (`INFO` -> `FINE`/`FINEST`) in `logging.properties` or `log4j.properties` (INFO, SEVERE, WARNING, INFO, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, FINEST or ALL), restart Tomat and check the logs,
- if nothing in logs, check if you're checking the right logs (`sudo lsof | grep -E "java.*(out|txt|log)$"`, `tail -f /var/log/tomcat7/*.log /var/log/tomcat7/*.txt /var/log/tomcat7/*.out`),
- when using `log4j` logging system, make sure you [initialized it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1140358/55075) by placing libs and `log4j.properties` into the right folder and configuring it,
- test BASIC authentication with cURL:

  - without credentials:

    ```
    $ curl -vv http://example.com:8983/solr/
    ```

    Normally request should return *HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized* and the "*WWW-Authenticate*" header should indicate *Basic* authentication is required.
  - with credentials:

    ```
    $ curl -vv -u tomcat:tomcat http://example.com:8983/solr/
    ```

    The request should be sent with an "Authorization" header and it should authenticate.  If your credentials are invalid, you should get: *HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized*. If the user is authenticated, but does not have access to view the resource you should get: *HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden*.
- maybe a user lock out mechanism has been activated for [too many failed authentication attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15337296/55075) ([LockOutRealm](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/LockOutRealm.html)),
- stop and run Tomcat manually (in the same way as in: `ps wuax | grep ^tomcat`), e.g.:

  ```
  # ps wuax | grep ^tomcat
  tomcat7    884  /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties ... org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
  $ /etc/init.d/tomcat7 stop
  $ sudo sudo -u tomcat7 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java ...  -Dorg.apache.catalina.level=FINEST org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
  ```

  Alternatively start using `catalina.sh` script like:

  ```
  $ . /etc/default/tomcat7
  $ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat7 CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat7 CATALINA_PID=/var/run/tomcat7.pid CATALINA_TMPDIR=/tmp LOGGING_CONFIG="-Dorg.apache.catalina.level=FINEST"
  $ /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh run
  ```

  Or in [debug mode](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing):

  ```
  $ JPDA_SUSPEND=y catalina.sh jpda start
  ```

  and check your `catalina.out` log.
- last resort is to debug process by: `sudo strace -fp PID`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the user which is running the tomcat has access to the folder where FreeShim is located.

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx < dir of FreeShim >
```

This worked for me.